# Rails has and belongs to many does not keep relation information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Given the following models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workspaces
end

class Workspace < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This code inserts a record into `workspaces` and `users_workspaces`:

```
User.last.workspaces.create
```

But, this one does not insert into `users_workspaces`:

```
User.last.workspaces.new.save
```

I need to do it this way:

```
w = Workspace.new
w.users << User.last
w.save
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `#build` method like :

```
User.last.workspaces.build.save
```

`collection.build(attributes = {})`

> Returns a new object of the collection type that has been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through the join table, but has not yet been saved.